# Upload code in codeplex

Tags: codeplex

I have a project with sourcecode. It is a visual studio 2010 solution. Now I want to upload the code as a project in codeplex. In codeplex I can create a new project, but can not upload the code. I can not find the option to upload the existing code from my hard drive.

Please send me if you have any solution.

Comment: OMG, their web interface is horrible, you have to click clone to see the Git URL the first time...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot upload the Source Code to codeplex, you use Git to push your code to their server.

They have a tutorial on their help site. You can use that to get to know how to upload the source code to their server.

https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Git%20with%20CodePlex&referringTitle=Source%20Control

Go there and learn to upload code to their server for public usage.